# Playing duffie lassie?

Tags: scottish-english

I remember when I was in Edinburgh my English teacher taught me an expression that was supposed to be Scottish. It was something like *play the duffie lassie* which should mean "that a girl plays dumb".

Anyway, I have Google around but cannot find it.
Does this expression exist? At least, in Scotland?

Comment: I have lived in Edinburgh for years and most of my friends are Scottish, but I've never heard this. Could be a Highlands thing.

Answer (score 5):

Alexander Warrack & William Grant, *Chambers Scots Dictionary* (1911) has these entries for *duffie* and *duffy*:

> **Duffie,** *adj.* blunt, round-pointed.
>
> **Duffie,** *adj.* soft, spongy; foolish; cowardly. Cf. Doughy.
>
> **Duffy,** *adj.* powdery, used of coal that crumbles when struck by the poker; soft, spongy; stupid.—*n.* a soft, silly fellow.

The cross-referenced word *doughy* has this entry:

> **Doughy,** *adj.* half-baked; 'soft'; foolish; cowardly. Cf. Daighie.

And for *daighie*, Chambers has this:

> **Daighie,** *adj.* doughy; soft, flabby; spiritless; cowardly; childish; ill-dressed; used of rich ground: composed of clay and sand properly mixed.

A Google Books search for "duffie lassie," "duffy lassie," "duffie lass," and "duffy lass" yields no meaningful matches, suggesting either that you misheard the words or that the expression has left virtually no footprint in published writings in the Google Books database. Still, the second definition of *duffie* and the first (and only) of *duffy* in Chambers (above) appear to match the meaning of "duffie lassie" that your teacher in Edinburgh gave you. So perhaps a "duffie [or duffy] lassie" is indeed a girl who behaves in a soft, spongy, foolish [or stupid] way, whether she really is so or is simply playing a part.

Comment: The saying the asker quotes is really ‘to _play_ the duffie lassie’, so if _duffie_ does indeed mean ‘stupid, foolish’, it’s a straightforward phrase (hardly even an idiom). “Don’t you be playing the daft lass on me, you know perfectly well what I mean!” would be completely understandable in regular speech nowadays, and from there it’s only a matter of ascertaining whether _duffie_ could mean ‘daft’—which you have beautifully shown that it could.